# How can I count the number of cells whose value is lower than the cell above?

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a column on numerical values. I want a formula, **not a macro**, that can be placed somewhere on the sheet to count how many values in that list are lower than the value above.

For example, given the column

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 5
> 1
> 6
> 5

The function should return 2, as there are two values lower than the value above ("1 below 5" and "5 below 6").

Due to the nature of this project, I cannot use a macro to do this. Additionally, the data is **not** stored in a table, nor can it be converted into a table.

Is there a formulaic way to do this in a single cell for an arbitrarily long list?

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT with offset but identical sized ranges:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A6>A2:A7))
```

[image]